# Importing a WordPress database with phpMyAdmin - #1044 error - Access Denied for User

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I exported a database from a local XAMPP setup, and I now need to import it onto my client's webserver. I no longer have access to the local machine where I created the export, so I really need to work with the SQL file I have on hand. However, when I try to import, I'm getting this error:

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `breakawayinn`
-- 
DROP DATABASE `breakawayinn`;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user '[redacted]'@'localhost' to database 'breakawayinn'
```

I've seen this question asked numerous times, but the issue is always with a CREATE DATABASE statement. This file doesn't have a CREATE DATABASE statement; it appears to be hanging on DROP DATABASE. I'm really not familiar with MySQL at all (I followed a tutorial to export the database originally), I'm just trying to migrate a WordPress site from my local machine to the client's server. Any ideas how I can fix the SQL file to make the import work?

Comment: the user account you're using hasn't been granted `drop` privs. that's all: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop

Comment: Thanks for the help Marc! Could you give me more detailed instructions for granting that privilege to the user? I'm kind of in over my head here.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Thanks Marc, but I'm still confused. I've tried adding this line to the SQL file:

GRANT ALL ON breakawayinn TO 'cpses_mu0ZerDMHT'@'localhost';

When I put this line directly above the DROP DATABASE line, I get the following error message:

#1046 - No database selected

But when I put it directly after the DROP DATABASE line, I get the same #1044 error as above. What am I not doing right?

Comment: is that the account you're using to load the dump? `mysql -u cpses_mu0ZerDMHT -p < dump.sql`?